# Programmatically create MySites for Users with FBA

Tags: development, my-site, forms-authentication, claims-based-auth

I am trying to create MySites for users programmatically but I am receiving the following error:

*My Site creation failure for user '' for site URL 'http://goaccel-app2:1000/sites/mysites/personal/'.*

Exception:

*Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PersonalSiteCreateException: A failure was encountered while attempting to create the site. ---> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: User cannot be found.*

I am using Forms Based Authentication (FBA) with SharePont 2010 Foundation

This is the code I am using:

```
public void MySite(SPUser AdminUser,string username, string sitehost)
    {
       sitehost agrument given <mysitehost domain>
        var superToken = AdminUser.UserToken;
        UserProfile profile = null;
        HttpContext con = HttpContext.Current;
        try
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                string sAccount = string.Empty;
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(sitehost, superToken))
                {
                    SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
                    HttpContext.Current = null;
                    UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(context);
                    //  SPUser NewUser = web.EnsureUser(web.CurrentUser.LoginName);
                    SPUser NewUser = web.EnsureUser(username);
                  SPUser NewUser = web.EnsureUser(web.CurrentUser.LoginName);
               sAccount = NewUser.LoginName;
   if (profileManager.UserExists(sAccount))
       {
     profile = profileManager.GetUserProfile(sAccount);
           if (profile.PersonalSite == null)
               {
                profile.CreatePersonalSite();
                SPSite newSite = new SPSite(profile.PersonalSite.ID);
              SPWeb newWeb = newSite.RootWeb;
                 newWeb.SiteAdministrators.Add(NewUser.LoginName, NewUser.Email, NewUser.Name, NewUser.Notes);
             newWeb.Features.Add(new Guid("9DCBD980-1FE9-421B-90FD-4FE766D02A65"));
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your MySites Configuration?

Comment: Is self-service site creation running on your server?

Comment: yeah..self-service site creation is already running on my server

Comment: @jesus Shelby.. i have pass mysites Host name via function.plz check my below code which is m editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a personal site for a user you should be using something like this:

```
profile.CreatePersonalSite();
```

Here is a link to some documentation on the CreatePersonalSite() method.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms518678.aspx

Also, be sure to properly dispose your SPSite and SPWeb objects.

Comment: My doubts is when m going in Central Administration-Manage service application-User Profile Service- Mysite Setting -> Setup My sites. when m click on Setup Mysites link i got this one error                                         "Cannot create an object of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.LocStringId' from its string representation 'SiteAdminPersonalSite_SocialSecurityTrimmerEnabledSectionTitle_Text' for the 'TitleLocId' property. " so my thoughts thats this issue causes problem when in Create mysite.  Do you have any idea to solve this issue?

Comment: Was this a new install or an upgrade from a previous version?  What language packs do you have installed?  The error you mentioned suggests other technical issues with the farm.

Comment: without upgrading i facing this error than after I upgraded sharepoint Server 2010 with August 2010 CU(After Searching Google).. Till I got this error :(

Comment: You didn't answer the language pack question.  The items you listed are related to localization.  Which language packs are installed, and were those properly patched?

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/2bUMX2YBTN
here i have attach link for Language Pack.